# I have a frontend application which we do authentication using rest api. Now we want to add login with google functionality by using firebase

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, firebase

So how to handle the token that comes from firebase. The token generates by rest api and firebase are completely different. So how to authenticate the users who choose to login with google.

So the token is completely different from my rest api. Since secret key and algorithms are  completely different. My rest api return 401 code when I pass token that generated by firebase. Please help me. The backend is NodeJS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So usually in these cases when you get a token from the third party auth providers, here in case of firebase, Check for the validity of the token with the firebase using their token verification endpoint or if any library is available for nodejs, after the verification, you will find the payload of the token that contains the email id of the user

Now using that email id, check against your database if that email exists or not.
If exists, then issue a new token of your own rest api and send it to the user.

If the email does not exist, create a new user from the data obtained from the payload, you will usually find first name, last name, email, and few other basic info about the user.

This way continue with the normal process of authentication.